# Jest - How to test that element exists in my component

Tags: lwc-jest

I'm trying to do a simple test that confirms that a field (from an object) exists on a javascript lwc component.  The field I'm trying to check is `Sweep_Day__c` (from the account object).  This field is displayed in the html. I know the way I have it now is not working, as I can change the `Sweep_Day__c` field name to anything and the test still passes. Thanks.

This is my Jest:

```javascript
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import lwcRetailerInformationHub from 'c/lwcRetailerInformationHub';

const mountElement = () => {
  const element = createElement("c-lwc-Retailer-Information-Hub", {
    is: lwcRetailerInformationHub
  });
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  return element;
};

describe("check for field existence and non-existence", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
    while (document.body.firstChild) {
      document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
    }
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  async function flushPromises() {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  function getSelector(element, selector) {
    return element.shadowRoot.querySelector(selector);
  }

  it("Sweep_Day__c should exist on the component", async () => {
    const element = mountElement();
    const sweepDay__c = getSelector(element, "Sweep_Day__c");   
    expect(sweepDay__c).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

This is where the field is displayed on the HTML:

```html
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-5">                               
     lightning-output-field field-name="Sweep_Day__c"></lightning-output-field>                                        
</div>
```

I tried this Jest as well, The test passes but shouldn't.

```javascript
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import lwcRetailerInformationHub from 'c/lwcRetailerInformationHub';

describe("check for field existence and non-existence", () => {
afterEach(() => {
    // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
    while (document.body.firstChild) {
      document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
    }
  });

  it("Sweep_Day__c should exist on page", () => {
    const component = createElement("c-lwc-Retailer-Information-Hub", {
      is: lwcRetailerInformationHub
    });
    document.body.appendChild(component);
    const testedElement =
      component.shadowRoot.querySelector("xxxSweep_Day__c");
    expect(testedElement).toBeDefined()
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify your `jest` test as follows.

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import jesttestdemo from 'c/jesttestdemo';

describe('c-jesttestdemo', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // Clean up DOM elements after each test
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });

    it('contains a lightning-output-field for Sweep_Day__c', () => {

        const OUTPUT_FIELDS = ['Sweep_Day__c'];
        const element = createElement('c-jesttestdemo', {
            is: jesttestdemo
        });
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        const outputFieldNames = Array.from(
            element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('lightning-output-field')
        ).map((outputField) => outputField.fieldName);
        expect(outputFieldNames).toEqual(OUTPUT_FIELDS);
    });
});
```

You can find variety of jest examples for most of the use cases in [LWC Recepies](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes)

`toBeDefined` only checks for undefined. Which in your case is `null`, hence `toBeDefined` wont work.

https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tobedefined

> .toBeDefined()
> Use .toBeDefined to check that a variable is not undefined. For example, if you want to check that a function fetchNewFlavorIdea() returns something, you can write:
>
> test('there is a new flavor idea', () => {
> expect(fetchNewFlavorIdea()).toBeDefined(); });

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I'll try this solution today.

Comment: I had to make a small change to the expect statement, then it worked fine.  Thank you! expect(outputFieldNames).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(OUTPUT_FIELDS));